# How to use firebase authentication in c#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to use Firebase in C#, I set the rules of the cloud storage as :

```
allow read, write: if auth.uid == 'testing';
```

I found this library https://medium.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-c-library-8e5e1c30acc2 but I don't understand how to use it to fit my rules